# The problem of SQL statement in sqldf in R?

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

I met some very strainge issue concerning with sqldf.

Example:

```
sqldf("select REGN, NII from dataframe ")
```

Even with very simple query this function returns an the following error:

```
Ошибка в result_create(conn@ptr, statement) :too many SQL variables
```

Here is the data sample I use as a result of `dput(head(dataframe))`

```
structure(list(REGN = c(1L, 21L, 23L, 52L, 53L, 55L), NII = c(5136380L, 
30322L, 291812L, 92561L, 120618L, 140652L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Edit:
But when I run the similar code to this dataframe:

```
structure(list(date_start = c("2008-04-01", "2016-04-01", "2019-04-01", 
"2020-04-01", "2021-04-01"), date_end = c("2016-04-01", "2019-04-01", 
"2020-04-01", "2021-04-01", "3000-01-01")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

everything works.

The results of `sessioninfo()`:

```
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Russian_Russia.1251 
[2] LC_CTYPE=Russian_Russia.1251   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Russian_Russia.1251
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=Russian_Russia.1251    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] openxlsx_4.1.0       sqldf_0.4-11        
 [3] RSQLite_2.1.1        gsubfn_0.7          
 [5] proto_1.0.0          stringr_1.4.0       
 [7] reshape2_1.4.3       dplyr_0.8.0.1       
 [9] readxl_1.3.1         foreign_0.8-71      
[11] RevoUtils_11.0.3     RevoUtilsMath_11.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] zip_2.0.1        Rcpp_1.0.1       cellranger_1.1.0
 [4] pillar_1.3.1     compiler_3.5.3   plyr_1.8.4      
 [7] tools_3.5.3      RPostgres_1.1.1  digest_0.6.18   
[10] bit_1.1-14       memoise_1.1.0    tibble_2.1.1    
[13] pkgconfig_2.0.2  rlang_0.3.4      DBI_1.0.0       
[16] rstudioapi_0.10  hms_0.4.2        bit64_0.9-7     
[19] tidyselect_0.2.5 glue_1.3.1       R6_2.3.0        
[22] tcltk_3.5.3      purrr_0.3.2      blob_1.1.1      
[25] magrittr_1.5     assertthat_0.2.1 stringi_1.4.3   
[28] chron_2.3-53     crayon_1.3.4
```

The results of `ls()`:

```
[1] "complete"             "con"                 
 [3] "dateAn"               "df"                  
 [5] "df_3"                 "df_4"                
 [7] "df_inval"             "df_inval_q"          
 [9] "df_itogo"             "df_itogo_q"          
[11] "df_itogo2"            "df_rub"              
[13] "df_rub_q"             "df1"                 
[15] "f102_dates"           "f102_maket"          
[17] "f102_maket_1"         "f102_maket_long"     
[19] "f102_maket_long_symb" "i"                   
[21] "j"                    "k"                   
[23] "levelFunc"            "listdbf"             
[25] "m"                    "MainPath"            
[27] "query_compos"         "split"               
[29] "subtract"
```

What's the matter?

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(head(dataframe))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas the question was editted

Comment: It works for me using the 6 element dataframe.  Do you get the same error there?  Maybe you need to update some packages.

Comment: @user2554330 yes. I got this problem even with extra small dataframe. Even after updating sqldf package

Comment: `sqldf` depends on other packages; maybe one of those needs updating.

Comment: @user2554330 unfortunately is doesn't help

Comment: Could you show us the result of `sessionInfo()`?  Maybe it will give a hint as to the issue.  `ls()` could also be informative.

Comment: @user2554330 the required info is provided

Comment: Your R version is quite old; current is 4.0.5. Some of your packages are also older than current ones:  I have RSQLite 2.2.4, bit 4.0.4, bit64 4.0.5, etc.  The other big differences between our systems are that you are using a Russian locale (you can set the environment variable LANG=C to get R to start in a vanilla locale), and you are on Windows, I'm on macOS.  My guess would be the outdated versions are the issue, but it could be something else.

Comment: Using sqldf 0.4.11, RSQLite 2.2.7, DBI 1.1.1 and 
"R version 4.0.4 Patched (2021-03-05 r80091)" and setting `Sys.setlocale(locale = "Russian")` on Windows it works for me.

Comment: @user2554330 Iupdated R and all other packages. Bur now another porblem arises `RIGHT and FULL OUTER JOINs are not currently supported`, because my initial query containes `full join`. Is there an alternative of `full join` in sqldf?

Comment: DavidBijoyan, for the last question, [`sqlite full join`](https://www.google.com/search?q=sqlite+full+join) lists several reasonable resources for working around that. As to the original need, though, it's difficult to know since this is the first time you've mentioned `JOIN` in this question: we have no query including that, and the sample data frames you provided appear to have nothing in common that could be part of a join. Your question really needs to be self-contained and fully reproducible on its own, not reliant on things in your R instance/console.